# How do I project an image by a disparity map?

Tags: opencv

I have a stereo pair, and a map of vectors that represent the pixel-pixel disparity between my left image to my right image. I would like to project my left image into my right image, using the disparity map.

I am stuck on how to achieve this with some accuracy, given that the disparity map vectors are floating point, not clean integer values that map directly to the pixels in my right image.

Answer (score 2):

First question - are your images rectified? (See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_rectification) If yes, you can generate the "right image" from the given left image and the disparity map, changing each pixel's column (or x) coordinate by the disparity amount. There will be some blank pixels due to occlusions, however.

Sub-pixel accuracy images, however,  cannot be generated in this way, as you noted. One thing you can do is round the disparities to integer values and create the image. Another thing you can do is create an image that is 2x or 5x or 10x (or however many times) larger than your input image, and then use this additional resolution to get "sub-pixel" accuracy for your projection image. But you will get some holes this way, and would likely need to interpolate to generate a piece-wise smooth final result.